# How To Delete Certain Rows/Cells Using Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

Good day. I hope all is well.

I am new in Google sheet and I am trying to figure out what code/script should I use to delete all rows with in a certain Column that is equal to **"1"**. Need your help please. I want it to work like these:

1st Step: It will filter all rows/cells in **Col N** that contains **"1"**.
2nd Step: It will **delete** those rows/cells that was filtered.
Last Step: It will remove the filter in **Col N** and filter **Col N** again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all rows with value 1 in column N

```
function deleteRowsWithValueOne() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var column = 'N'; // Specify the column letter where your data is located

  var data = sheet.getRange(column + '1:' + column + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  var firstRow = -1;
  var lastRow = -1;

  // Find the first and last row with value 1 in the specified column
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === 1) { // Assuming the value is numeric 1
      if (firstRow === -1) {
        firstRow = i + 1; // Adding 1 because arrays are zero-indexed, but rows are one-indexed
      }
      lastRow = i + 1; // Adding 1 because arrays are zero-indexed, but rows are one-indexed
    }
  }

  if (firstRow !== -1 && lastRow !== -1) {
    // Delete the rows within the range from firstRow to lastRow
    sheet.deleteRows(firstRow, lastRow - firstRow + 1);
    Logger.log('Deleted rows with value 1 from row ' + firstRow + ' to ' + lastRow);
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows found with value 1.');
  }
}
```